# How to find boot record of external HDD

Tags: linux, external-hdd, bootable, mbr

I have an internal NoteBook HDD hooked up to a Linux machine externally via USB and want to check if this HDD has some sort of boot record on it.

- I have no access to BIOS and can not boot my device from this HDD
  externally
- I can not hook this HDD up internally to any machine at
  the moment
- Should there be a boot record I have no idea what type it may have been.
- The HDD is mounted as a 250 GB empty drive and I can paste file into the main folder and delete them with no issues so seems it is working fine as a storage device.

The output for

```
sudo file -s /dev/sdb5
```

is:

```
/dev/sdb5: data
```

Is there a way to find out using the command line in Linux if there is any boot records on it and if so what type?

Comment: As a start, what is the output of `sudo file -s /dev/sdb` (or whatever the name of the device is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### BIOS boot loader, MBR

Please check the whole drive (point to the drive's head end),

```
sudo file -s /dev/sdX
sudo file -s /dev/sdb   # example: device b
```

Do **not** point to a partition,

```
sudo file -s /dev/sdb5  # example: device b, partition 5
```

### UEFI bootloader

In UEFI mode the computer needs nothing in the boot sector at the head end, but right behind it there should be a partition table.

There is usually a small EFI system partition with a FAT file system.

There is often (but must not be) a GUID partition table, GPT.

Check with

```
sudo parted -ls
sudo fdisk -l
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdX
```

### Cloned iso file

You can clone from an iso file to a USB pendrive or another mass storage device. Then there will be an iso9660 file system, and it can often be booted both in BIOS and UEFI mode.

Check with

```
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

Comment: A removable media is bootable in UEFI mode if it contains a filesystem that is recognizable to the UEFI firmware (FAT32 support is mandatory in the UEFI specification; ISO9660 often also works; other filesystem types may or may not be supported), **and** that filesystem contains an UEFI bootloader in the standard fallback path for the correct hardware architecture, e.g. `\EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` for 64-bit x86 architecture, `\EFI\BOOT\bootia32.efi` for 32-bit x86, or `\EFI\BOOT\bootaa64.efi` for 64-bit ARM hardware.

Answer (score 0):

That drive seems to be recognized correctly. What be the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`? And, I can't speak for GPT drives, but what is the hexdump of the drive's first 512 bytes? Does it end in `55 AA`? If yes, chances are it's a correct (DOS type) MBR. Other text / string may give an indication what system we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the partitions of the external device:

```
# parted /dev/sda
```

or

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

Change `sda` to whatever your device is.

If the device was used to boot another machine it will have a boot partition. You can probably identify it based on its size. If it was an MBR scheme, the boot partition could be roughly 200MiB. If it was an EFI, it could be upwards of 550MiB.

You’ve shown that the Linux machine recognizes the external device, therefore, you should see the partitions with the above commands. The boot partition is likely `sdb1`.

If the external HDD was formatted as a partitionless device, there will not be a boot partition. In this case, there “should” be a boot directory. However, you probably will not be able to read the data, depending on how it was formatted.